# sudo ./starling start works well but sudo service starling start fails

Tags: ruby, ubuntu, rubygems, starling-server

`sudo ./starling start` works well but `sudo service starling start` fails

```
$ sudo ./starling start
 * Starting Starling Server...                  [ OK ] 
$ sudo ./starling stop
 * Stop Starling Server...                  [ OK ] 
$ sudo service starling stop
 * Starting Starling Server...                                        
/home/keating/.rvm/rubies/ruby-1.9.2-p290/lib/ruby/site_ruby/1.9.1/rubygems/dependency.rb:247:in
`to_specs': Could not find starling (>= 0) amongst [minitest-1.6.0,
rake-0.8.7, rdoc-2.5.8] (Gem::LoadError)    from
/home/keating/.rvm/rubies/ruby-1.9.2-p290/lib/ruby/site_ruby/1.9.1/rubygems/dependency.rb:256:in
`to_spec'   from
/home/keating/.rvm/rubies/ruby-1.9.2-p290/lib/ruby/site_ruby/1.9.1/rubygems.rb:1229:in
`gem'   from /home/keating/.rvm/gems/ruby-1.9.2-p290/bin/starling:18:in
`<main>'
```

**The error above is 'cannot find gem starling'**

Following the starling file(located in /etc/init.d, rwxrwxrwx):

```
set -e
LOGFILE=/var/log/starling/starling.log SPOOLDIR=/var/spool/starling
PORT=22122 LISTEN=127.0.0.1 PIDFILE=/var/run/starling.pid



NAME=starling DESC="Starling"
INSTALL_DIR=/home/keating/.rvm/gems/ruby-1.9.2-p290/bin/
DAEMON=$INSTALL_DIR/$NAME SCRIPTNAME=/etc/init.d/$NAME
OPTS="-d"

. /lib/lsb/init-functions


d_start() {
        log_begin_msg "Starting Starling Server..."
        start-stop-daemon --start --quiet --pidfile $PIDFILE --exec $DAEMON -- $OPTS || log_end_msg 1
        log_end_msg 0 }

d_stop() {
        log_begin_msg "Stopping Starling Server..."
        start-stop-daemon --stop --quiet --pidfile $PIDFILE || log_end_msg 1
        log_end_msg 0 }

case "$1" in start) d_start ;; stop) d_stop ;;
restart|force-reload|reload) d_stop sleep 2 d_start ;;
*) echo "Usage: $SCRIPTNAME {start|stop|restart|force-reload}" exit 3 ;; esac

exit 0
```

Comment: Please don't close the question, I am working hard on it for days.

Comment: Hi Keating, interesting question but it doesn't belong on this programming QA site, serverfault would be more appropriate.

Comment: What if you change sudo service starling to sudo service ./starling ?

Comment: There is the same error when I change sudo service starling to sudo service ./starling

Comment: Okay, I have never tried serverfault, maybe this is a chance.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

was starling created with a wrapper script from rvm?  http://rvm.io/integration/god/

Comment: Really thank you DGM, I have worked hard on it for several days.

Comment: To clarify, there's more to rvm than just hitting the right binary - there's the ruby and gem path that needs set up too, and the wrapper script is what sets it up.